# CS0618 'ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig(string)' is obsolete

Tags: c#, winforms, warnings

When I try to run my project I got the following warning

> Warning   CS0618  'ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig(string)' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection'

I don't know how to fix please help me....

Comment: `@JonathanWatson` Actually is may be same but it's occurs in windows application. Also I tried to added a `System.Configuration` but is not works.

Comment: It's actually a duplicate. The warning is telling you exactly what you should be doing. Use the recommended method instead of the obsolete method. Alternatively you can suppress the warning in the project's build settings.